# How to get all the post titles on a specific page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, title

I want to display all the posts on a specific page called "Articles".

However, when I used `the_title();` in a loop, it seems that the title of this page is displayed instead.

**relative code in `articles.php` (linked to the `Articles` page created in dashboard)**

```
<div class="container">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="content">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>                
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>                                            
                </div>                                                    
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**`content.php`**

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-header section medium-padding">   
    <div class="post-meta-top"> 
        <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>

        <?php 
            if ( comments_open() ) {
                echo '<span class="sep">/</span> '; 
                if ( is_single() )
                    comments_popup_link( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments', 'post-comments' ); 
                else
                    comments_number( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments' ); 
            }
        ?> 
    </div>

    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>           
</a>
```

This part works well in `index.php`.

Comment: Can you post your loop code?

Comment: @Johann Kratzik I have updated my question. This part works in `index.php`, but has problem in `articles.php` which used as a template page for **Page "Articles"**  that created in **Dashboard**.

Comment: Is this all your code? You need to define the loop itself with WP_Query() in the page template. Otherwise only the current page loop will be displayed.

Comment: @Johann Kratzik Actually I used this part in `index.php` first, which worked well. And then directly moved it to this page template. I just start learning to use WordPress. Could you please provide an example for how to define the loop itself with WP_Query()?

Comment: Do you only want to display the titles, maybe linked to the posts? Also, did you did you define the page template correctly with the comment at top? Like this: /* Template Name: Some Template */

Comment: Sure the code works in index.php because this template is displaying all posts by default.

Comment: @Johann Kratzik I did define the page template with the comment. I intended to display each post with **title** (include link to the post), **date**, and **number of comments**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a new template articles.php inside the folder of content.php and insert this code:

```
<?php
$articles = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

while ( $articles->have_posts() ) :
$articles->the_post();
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-header section medium-padding">   
<div class="post-meta-top"> 
    <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>

    <?php 
        if ( comments_open() ) {
            echo '<span class="sep">/</span> '; 
            if ( is_single() )
                comments_popup_link( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments', 'post-comments' ); 
            else
                comments_number( '0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments' ); 
        }
    ?> 
</div>

<h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>           
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Step 2:** In articles.php replace this line:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

with this one:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'articles' ); ?>
```

Not tested but it should work.

Comment: Great :) I'm glad to hear